# Работа в android studio без аппаратного ускорения

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, amd

Скачал последнюю версию Android Studio(AS), но процессор(amd) не поддерживает ускорение, а AS требует android emulator hypervisor driver for amd, есть ли способ работать без аппаратного ускорения в AS?

Comment: установили гипервизор https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/10/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for.html ?

Comment: В автоматическом режиме он не устанавливается

Comment: никто ведь не запрещает сделать это все ручками